# UITextView custom input (No keyboard) iOS

Tags: ios, uitextview, scrollview

I am using an UITextView where I append input text based on custom buttons (No keyboard). It all works fine except that when the text exceeds to a new line, the UITextField crops text instead of scrolling down to the new line (as happens when you input text with the system keyboard)..

How can I fix this behavior?

Comment: UITextField or UITextView, which is it?

Comment: Can you include the code where you update the text view text from your custom keyboard?

Comment: self.textView.text = [self.textView.text stringByAppendingString:[sender currentTitle]];
where actually sender rapresents the button pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to scroll the text view yourself as the length of the text increases - I imagine the system keyboard does this itself too.

The relevant method is `scrollRangeToVisible:`. The range argument should be the end of the text you have just inserted into the text view.

Comment: `NSMakeRange([self.textview.text length],0);` will select the end of the text

Comment: I found that earlier but that's exactly what I need, so thanks !